# Windows phone 8.1 how to close StorageFile?

Tags: c#, image, file, windows-phone-8.1

i m having a little problem. I m creating image with grayScale filter by using StorageFile. The problem starts when i try to set filter on second image. First time i take picture and set filter and its ok, second time when i take picture and try to set filter i got error message : `Access is denied. Exception from HRESULT: ...` . Third time when i take pic, i can set filter, fourth time i got error again and so on. I know that problem is that app still use that same StorageFile and its locked, but i don't know how to close that file.

Here i create StorageFile file:

```
async private void Capture_Photo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ImageEncodingProperties imgFormat = ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg();
    InMemoryRandomAccessStream imageStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
    await newCapture.CapturePhotoToStreamAsync(imgFormat, imageStream);
    BitmapDecoder dec = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(imageStream);
    BitmapEncoder enc = await BitmapEncoder.CreateForTranscodingAsync(imageStream, dec);
    string currentorientation = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().CurrentOrientation.ToString();
    switch (currentorientation)
    {
        case "Landscape":
            enc.BitmapTransform.Rotation = BitmapRotation.None;
            break;
        case "Portrait":
            enc.BitmapTransform.Rotation = BitmapRotation.Clockwise90Degrees;
            break;
        case "LandscapeFlipped":
            enc.BitmapTransform.Rotation = BitmapRotation.Clockwise180Degrees;
            break;
        case "PortraitFlipped":
            enc.BitmapTransform.Rotation = BitmapRotation.Clockwise270Degrees;
            break;
        default:
            enc.BitmapTransform.Rotation = BitmapRotation.None;
            break;
    }
    await enc.FlushAsync();
    string naziv = "IMG_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".jpg";
    naziv = naziv.Insert(12, "_");
    file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(
        naziv,
        CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    var filestream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
    await RandomAccessStream.CopyAsync(imageStream, filestream);
    BitmapImage bmpImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(file.Path));
    var obj = App.Current as App;
    obj.fileTransfer = file;
    obj.ImageToEdit = bmpImage;
    await newCapture.StopPreviewAsync();
    bmpImage = null;
    await imageStream.FlushAsync();
    await filestream.FlushAsync();
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(EditImage));
}
```

And this is grayScale filter:

```
 private async void ConvertToGrayScale()
{

    var obj = App.Current as App;
    StorageFile file = obj.fileTransfer;
    try {
        if (obj.isCrooped == true && obj.writebleImg != null) {
            file = await WriteableBitmapToStorageFile(obj.writebleImg);
        }
        else {
            file = obj.fileTransfer;
        }
        BitmapDecoder decoder = null;

        using (IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType stream = await file.OpenReadAsync())
        {
            decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);

            // Get the first frame
            BitmapFrame bitmapFrame = await decoder.GetFrameAsync(0);

            // Save the resolution (will be used for saving the file later)
            //dpiX = bitmapFrame.DpiX;
            //dpiY = bitmapFrame.DpiY;

            // Get the pixels
            PixelDataProvider dataProvider =
                await bitmapFrame.GetPixelDataAsync(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
                                                    BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied,
                                                    new BitmapTransform(),
                                                    ExifOrientationMode.RespectExifOrientation,
                                                    ColorManagementMode.ColorManageToSRgb);

            byte[] pixels = dataProvider.DetachPixelData();

            // Create WriteableBitmap and set the pixels
            WriteableBitmap srcBitmap = new WriteableBitmap((int)bitmapFrame.PixelWidth,
                                                         (int)bitmapFrame.PixelHeight);

            using (Stream pixelStream = srcBitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream())
            {
                await pixelStream.WriteAsync(pixels, 0, pixels.Length);
            }


            byte[] srcPixels = new byte[4 * srcBitmap.PixelWidth * srcBitmap.PixelHeight];

            using (Stream pixelStream = srcBitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream())
            {
                await pixelStream.ReadAsync(srcPixels, 0, srcPixels.Length);
            }

            // Create a destination bitmap and pixels array
            WriteableBitmap dstBitmap =
                    new WriteableBitmap(srcBitmap.PixelWidth, srcBitmap.PixelHeight);
            byte[] dstPixels = new byte[4 * dstBitmap.PixelWidth * dstBitmap.PixelHeight];


            for (int i = 0; i < srcPixels.Length; i += 4)
            {
                double b = (double)srcPixels[i] / 255.0;
                double g = (double)srcPixels[i + 1] / 255.0;
                double r = (double)srcPixels[i + 2] / 255.0;

                byte a = srcPixels[i + 3];

                double e = (0.21 * r + 0.71 * g + 0.07 * b) * 255;
                byte f = Convert.ToByte(e);

                dstPixels[i] = f;
                dstPixels[i + 1] = f;
                dstPixels[i + 2] = f;
                dstPixels[i + 3] = a;

            }

            // Move the pixels into the destination bitmap
            using (Stream pixelStream = dstBitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream())
            {
                await pixelStream.WriteAsync(dstPixels, 0, dstPixels.Length);
            }
            dstBitmap.Invalidate();

            // Display the new bitmap
            ImagePreview.Source = dstBitmap;

        }

    }
    catch (Exception err) { 
    err.StackTrace.ToString(); 
    }
}
```

On this line i got error :

```
using (IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType stream = await file.OpenReadAsync())
```

Comment: I meant to post the code in your previous question only, not as separate question, Anyhow its fine. Use using keyword,it will close the file automatically once its work is done. `using( StorageFile file = obj.fileTransfer;){...}`

Comment: I assume you want to save `dstBitmap` to gallery or are you converting `dstBitmap` to `StoageFile`

Comment: I already have StoradgeFile. dstBitmap  is used to save image to gallery ?

Comment: Are you assigning edited image again to StorageFile (i assume which you have picked from gallery). If you already did so it will be saved(actually replaced) to gallery

Comment: I have 2 ways of assigning image. First is by taking a picture with camera which user can edit later. User can just save image without editing. Second way is to choose for gallery image and then edit it and save. In both way i m  assigning image to StorageFile.  As i see, you don't understand me, so i will make it simpler. I just want to save image to phone, it can be WriteableBitmap , BitmapImage or StorageFile. Best solution would be with StorageFile.

Comment: I understood your flow.I think You dint understand the concepts properly. or you dint ask the question properly. StorageFile which you already have(which you use for editing is already saved in gallery). What you have to do is create a new file(StorageFIle) to save edited BitmapImage(Actually WritableBitmapImage).Isnt it?

Comment: Well i didn't know that. But why i don't see that storageFile in gallery ? Well i think you are right, i just want to make those images visible so user can see them in gallery

Comment: Because you dint create the new file. I ll post the answer in a while

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close the `filestream` right after you've written the data.

```
using (var filestream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
{
    await RandomAccessStream.CopyAsync(imageStream, filestream);
}
```